# How to call user defined function from another user defined function in bash?

Tags: bash-functions

I want to do this --

```
function swap(){ mv $1 $1._tmp && mv $2 $1 && mv $1._tmp $2; }
function alterpdf(){ swap(titlepage_$1.tex titlepage_$2.tex); swap(titlepage_$1.pdf,titlepage_$2.pdf); pdflatex allTitle    page.tex; }
```

My `swap` function works well. Now , I want to use the `swap` function inside the `alterpdf` function. But, this produces error --

[image]

Comment: How do you use the `swap` function when it works well?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal error messages, just post the text - it's simple to do in the type of gui terminal emulator program that you're using.

Comment: @ilkkachu `$swap file1 file2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you putting shell function parameters inside parentheses? Try this:

```
function alterpdf(){
  swap titlepage_$1.tex titlepage_$2.tex
  swap titlepage_$1.pdf titlepage_$2.pdf
  pdflatex allTitle page.tex
  }
```